# How to execute select clause based on if condition & applying multiple filters on the result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute the following query on SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Fid nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @max nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @min nvarchar(30) 
DECLARE @Value nvarchar(30) 

SET @Fid = '6'

SET @max = '317012' 
SET @min = '317061' 
SET @Value = 'ALL' 

IF(@Value = 'ALL') 
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM sample WHERE projectkey = 'Proj1'

IF(@Value = 'Next') 
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM sample WHERE msgid <= @min AND projectkey = 'Proj1'

IF(@Value = 'Previous') 
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM (SELECT TOP 50 * FROM sample WHERE projectkey = 'Proj1' AND msgid >= @max ORDER BY msgid ASC) as t ORDER BY msgid DESC

AND 

fid = (CASE WHEN @Fid = 'ALL' THEN fid WHEN @Fid = '' THEN fid ELSE @Fid END)
```

In above query, I'm trying to execute select clause based on if condition and based on the result given by select clause I want to apply where clause conditions as filters, on the result. I am trying to avoid the repetition of filters (i.e. where clause) in every if block. How can we implement or modify above query to achieve such output?

Comment: u can use dynamic sql , build query in a string and execute it at end

Comment: @mmhasannn Thanks for your suggestion but the requirement is to execute the query as is on database.

Comment: why don't you use a case like you did in your last statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT TOP 50 * FROM sample WHERE projectkey = 'Proj1' and ((@Value = 'ALL')
    or (msgid <= @min  and @Value = 'Next')
    or (msgid >= @max and @Value = 'Previous'))

   order by 
   case when  @Value = 'Previous'
   then
   msgid 
   end 
   desc
```

Comment: Would be better to move the projectkey='proj1' outside of the brackets and just do it like "WHERE projectkey='proj1' AND ((firstand) or (secondand) or (thirdand))" seeing as the projectkey is the same for all 3 conditions

Comment: I have tried your query but the result is not getting filtered with fid = 6. Please check original query for reference & update your solution to bring the expected result.

Comment: Great , it was my mistake,it is working perfect. I will  get back to you in case of any query.

Comment: Can you please recheck the condition in original post when @Value='Previous' , ORDER BY msgid ASC , i.e. the inner sub query , will you please update the solution according to this ?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,but i would like you to please take a look at original post(i have updated it) for Previous as per the requirement. I need the view to be in DESC order but subquery processing in ASC order.

Comment: so instead of asc u can use desc

Comment: but it is affecting rest of the view,because only previous case needs this ASC processing but at the same time filter may ask for DESC . So the data view is getting in ASC.

Comment: Parent query result must be descending but subquery processing requirement is to take records in ASC then turn the result into DESC.

Comment: this doesnt make any sense because result will displayed in desc